# Reflection: Property-GetValue by Class-Type (so without an instantiated Object)

Tags: c#, reflection, types, properties, typeof

In our project we have multiple so-called `Projections`. These `Projection`-classes all have a string property with a get, called `ProjectionTypeName`. This `ProjectionTypeName` should be unique for all Projections.

Today I had the problem where two Projections had the same `ProjectionTypeName` which caused quite a lot of trouble. So I decided to make a UnitTest to prevent this from happening again.

I use the following method to get all the `Types` of all the `Projections`:

```
// The excluded abstract projections
private static readonly List<Type> AbstractProjections = new List<Type>
{
    typeof(AbstractRavenDbChangesProjection),
    typeof(AbstractRavenDbTimelineProjection)
};

private static IEnumerable<Type> GetAllProjectionTypes()
{
    return typeof(AbstractRavenDbChangesProjection)
        .Assembly
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(x => typeof(AbstractRavenDbChangesProjection).IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsInterface)
        .Except(AbstractProjections)
        .ToList();
}
```

Then I made the actual test:

```
[Test]
public void TestNoDuplicated()
{
    var noDuplicatedList = new Dictionary<Type, string>();
    var projectionTypes = GetAllProjectionTypes();
    foreach (var type in projectionTypes)
    {
        // TODO: Get projectionTypeName-value by Projection's Type
        var projectionTypeName = ??;

        Assert.IsFalse(noDuplicatedList.ContainsValue(projectionTypeName),
            "{0} has been found as ProjectionTypeName in two different Projections: {1} & {2}",
                projectionTypeName,
                noDuplicatedList.First(x => x.Value == projectionTypeName).Key,
                type);
            noDuplicatedList.Add(type, projectionTypeName);
    }   
}
```

I've looked around a bit and even tried [a piece of code by @JohnSkeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11162876/1682559), even though he states (and I quote):

> Please don't do this. Ever. It's ghastly. It should be trampled on,
>   cut up into little bits, set on fire, then cut up again. Fun though,
>   isn't it? ;)

But it looks like this has been changed since 2012 (when the answer was posted) and .NET now gives an error when you try this kind of reflection: `"System.Security.VerificationException : Operation could destabilize the runtime."`.

So, my question. How do I get the value of the string-property `ProjectionTypeName`, when I only have the `Type` of the class to my disposal (and not an actual instantiated object).

If I would had an instantiated object I would be able to do something like this:

```
myInstantiatedObject.GetType().GetProperty("ProjectionTypeName")
    .GetValue(myInstantiatedObject, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using custom attribute instead ?

```
[AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class)]
public sealed class ProjectionTypeNameAttribute : Attribute
{
  private string m_Name;

  public string Name
  {
    get { return m_Name; }
  }

  public ProjectionTypeNameAttribute(string name)
  {
    m_Name = name;
  }
}

[ProjectionTypeNameAttribute(ProjectionWhatever.PROJECTION_NAME)]
public class ProjectionWhatever
{
  public const string PROJECTION_NAME = "Whatever";

  // if you want to have property as well
  public string ProjectionTypeName
  {
    get
    {
      return PROJECTION_NAME;
    }
  }
}   

// query if type has attribute
var type = typeof(ProjectionWhatever);
var attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ProjectionTypeNameAttribute), false);
if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
{
  var attribute = (ProjectionTypeNameAttribute)attributes[0];
  // use attribute.Name
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that looks promising and much more cleaner. I'm currently pretty busy, so I don't have time to try it out yet with other higher priority issues needing my attention now that my problem is fixed with the UnitTest above. Still, +1 and I will put it on my TODO list when I have a bit more time.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found the answer to make John Skeet's code work, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263146/ilgenerator-how-to-use-unmanaged-pointers-i-get-a-verificationexception/8267324#8267324).

My problem was this line:

```
var dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod("TempUglyPropertyGetMethod", typeof(string),
    Type.EmptyTypes, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ManifestModule);
```

which was missing `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ManifestModule` as additional argument. This is my working test code:

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162652/c-sharp-get-property-value-without-creating-instance/11162876#11162876
var method = type.GetProperty("ProjectionTypeName").GetGetMethod();
var dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod("TempUglyPropertyGetMethod", typeof(string),
    Type.EmptyTypes, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ManifestModule);
var generator = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, method);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
var tempUglyPropertyGetMethod = (Func<string>)dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string>));
var projectionTypeName = tempUglyPropertyGetMethod();
```

Once again, don't use this in an actual project. I've only used it for this test case. To once again quote @JohnSkeet:

> Please don't do this. **Ever.** It's ghastly. It should be trampled
>   on, cut up into little bits, set on fire, then cut up again. Fun
>   though, isn't it? ;)

Comment: Why don't you use the simple delegate solution at the bottom of Jons answer?

Comment: @usr Because I can't do this part of his second code: `Func<MyClass`, since I can't use `MyClass`, I only have the `Type` of `MyClass`.

Comment: Make the delegate type using MakeGenericType and invoke it using DynamicInvoke. Saves you the IL generation which is obscure.